# AngularJs - bound service function executing multiple times

Tags: angularjs, factory, execution

I have following code example:

```
angular.module('test', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'test.template.html',
            controller: 'ctrlA',
            controllerAs: 'ctrlA'
        })
        .when('/page', {
            templateUrl: 'page.template.html',
            controller: 'ctrlB',
            controllerAs: 'ctrlB'
        });
})
.controller('ctrlA', function(testfactory) {
    this.value = "a";
    this.fnc = testfactory.getAmount;

})
.controller('ctrlB', function(testfactory) {
    this.value = "b";

    this.inc = function() {
        testfactory.incAmount();
    };

})
.factory('testfactory', function(){

    var amount = 0;

    return {

        incAmount: function() {
            amount++;
        },

        getAmount: function() {
            console.log("getAmount");
            return amount;
        }

    };
})
.run();
```

If I change the route from root to /page and back the getAmount function is executing multiple times. My main goal was to get the amount value from the service automatically if the amount gets increased by a different controller. How can I prevent the multiple execution of the function?

The template of ctrlA looks like

```
{{ctrlA.fnc()}}
```

Comment: Don't forger to upvote correct answer too, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable by passing reference to an object:

```
// testFactory

var data = {
    amount: 0
}

// ctrl, inject service, ...

this.data = factory.data

// template 

{{ctrl.data.amount}}
```

I wrote a blog post about this ([Model pattern for AngularJS](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/model-pattern-for-angular-js-67494389d6f)), you'll get automaticaly synchronzied data between service and multiple controllers.